# Go app CI with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, go, continuous-integration

I try to setup CI for Go app and Jenkins. Jenkins Go Plugin has been installed, it gets correct version of Go(currently it's 1.5.2).

Currently I have next:

1. Test repository with simple app https://github.com/Agnikay/Test-Go-Jenkins
2. Jenkins with installed Go Plugin(on VPS, Ubuntu 14.04, x86)
3. For build in Jenkins added as build step next:

   `cd src/main 
    go build main.go`

As result in artifacts existing 2 files - *main.go*(sources) and *main* (executable) for linux x86. If i use as build command `go build main.go -o server` error received: "named files must be .go files".
So, my questions are

1. If my app will contain much more code file, packages etc. should i still build it as `go build main.go`?
2. How correctly give name for `go build` output file to add it to the artifacts?
3. Should i use some kind of make file/script etc to collect dependencies on build machine? What is best practice here?

Comment: What do you mean by "build just do nothing ..."? Please show what you're doing, what your result is, and what you expect to happen.

Comment: I've update starting post with details. Previous was totally uninformative.

Comment: The error is because you're putting the `-o` flag after the file arguments. You don't need to name your `.go` files, you use the implied cwd (`go build -o server`), or the import path (`go install github.com/Agnikay/Test-Go-Jenkins`, `go build -o github.com/Agnikay/Test-Go-Jenkins`). See the docs:[How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html), [The Go Command](https://golang.org/cmd/go/), and/or the help output of each command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> named files must be .go files

You need to put the `.go` file last on the command-line.

```
go build -o server main.go
```

See:

- [Order of arguments matters with go build -o](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19717)

Related:

- [How to build executable with name other than Golang package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42706246/86967)